# First commercial DOS game?

Tags: history, ms-dos, software, ibm-pc, gaming

What was the first commercial game sold for use on IBM/MS/PC DOS after the IBM August 12, 1981 release.

Comment: What do you mean by "commercial"? Many games were passed around without being rebought; do those count? What if the author accepted this practice?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first game sold for use on the IBM PC was [Microsoft Adventure](http://www.mobygames.com/game/pc-booter/microsoft-adventure), which was available on the day the IBM PC was released (it was part of the launch, [along with VisiCalc, Easywriter etc.](https://archive.org/stream/byte-magazine-1981-10/1981_10_BYTE_06-10_Local_Networks#page/n33/mode/2up)). It was developed by Gordon Letwin (later of OS/2 fame) in 1979, based on the Colossal Cave mainframe game. It didn’t run on DOS though, it was a “booter” — you booted the computer with the game floppy, and it took care of everything, without a separate operating system. You can see it in action on [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/MicrosoftAdventure_DOS_1981). (Booters were quite common in those days, on the PC as well as on other micros; see [Mobygames’ list of PC booters](http://www.mobygames.com/browse/games/pc-booter/) for other examples.)

Based on [Mobygames’ list of DOS games released in 1981](http://www.mobygames.com/browse/games/dos/1981/), the likeliest candidate for first commercial *DOS* game is [IBM’s Arithmetic Games Set 1](http://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/arithmetic-games-set-1). Its contents suggest it was in development by August 1981, and probably complete not long after; the latest files on the original disk are dated September 23, 1981. Strictly speaking it’s a BASIC game, so it could have run using only the PC’s built-in ROM BASIC, without DOS; but as sold it used DOS. It’s also available to play on [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Arithmetic_Games_Set_1_1981). It’s not obvious whether any other games were released commercially earlier than that — some games were published in magazines and later published as commercial games. (Games published in magazines are arguably commercial games too, but it’s not quite the same.)

Answer (score 7):

Two other early "booters" were Microsoft's [Decathlon](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Microsoft_Decathlon_1982), and [Flight Simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Flight_Simulator#Flight_Simulator_1.0). [This site](https://www.dosgamesarchive.com) has a host of free DOS games for download, as does [this one](http://www.dosgames.com), and [this site](https://classicreload.com/microsoft-decathlon.html) allows visitors to play Decathlon in-browser.

Comment: The "Olympic Decathlon" link you have provided actually links to an Apple II game

Comment: @tofro AFAICT the link is for the DOS version (it boots in DOSBox); the Apple II is “Also For”, as in the game was also available for the Apple II...